# How to send external link to the telegram group from my bot using php? what should be the value to reply_markup in the link?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am using the telegram bot to send some text with external link in it as a button. i have tried with following code bot i dont know the Json value to send. please, can anybody can help me?

```
$sendMsg = file_get_contents($boturl."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".$c."&parse_mode=HTML&reply_markup=json_encode("?????")");
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
file_get_contents($boturl.'/sendmessage?chat_id='.$chat_id.'&text='.$c.'&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Press here to open URL","url":"https://example.com"}]]}');
```